# What is considered best practice when using nesting in SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

Say I have two classes, `.foo` and `.bar`.

Currently, there exist elements with the `.foo` class that may or may not have a descendant with the `.bar` class. However, every element with the `.bar` class is a descendant of an element with the `.foo` class. For example:

```
<div class="foo">
</div>

<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now say I'm using SCSS to style these classes. Which of the following options is better practice?

The first option is to nest `.bar` in `.foo`:

```
.foo {
    // some rules...

    .bar {
        // some rules...
    }
}
```

The second option is to have seperate top-level selectors for the two classes and use the parent selector to reference `.bar` when it is a descendant of `.foo`:

```
.foo {
    // some rules...
}

.bar {
    .foo & {
        // some rules...
    }
}
```

At the moment I am leaning towards the second option, mainly for the following reason:

Consider a case in the future where I want to add rules for the `.bar` class when it is not a descendant of `.foo`. In the first option I would have to create another top-level selector for `.bar` resulting in rules for that class appearing in two different places. Whereas, if I used the second option, I would simply add these rules to the existing top level `.bar` selector outside of the `.foo &` block.

Am I right in thinking that the second option is better practice?

Comment: Since your `.bar` is always inside `.foo`, I would go with #1. Or simply put styles only for `.bar` without referring parent class

Answer (score 3):

`SCSS` is used to simplify code and have minimal number of class and ids.

Your 1st-way is better as the code seems pretty simple and easy to read.

Your 2nd-way is unnecessarily creating more complexity to the code.

When you say that .bar is not inside .foo so you may directly write code for it and need not inside .foo.

consider:

```
<div class="foo">

  This is foo...

  <div class="bar">

    This is bar inside Foo ...

  </div>

</div>

<div class="bar">

  This is bar ...

</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.foo {
 color: red;

  .bar {
    color: green
  }
}

.bar {
  color: blue;
}
```